# Unzippping NSData with GTMNSData+zlib

Tags: iphone, nsdata, unzip, google-toolbox-for-mac

I download from Google Docs zipped NSData. The first bytes are PK.
I've read to unzip them I could use GTMNSData+zlib category.
Compiling my project, I obtain some errors, for example:

```
"_inflate", referenced from:
+[NSData(GTMZLibAdditions) gtm_dataByInflatingBytes:length:] in GTMNSData+zlib.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include zlib in your frameworks for your project. In XCode 4 select your project in the top of the Project Navigator, Go to Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries, click the + sign to add and search for libz.dylib, if you need a specific version just select the right version.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. Do you know how can I "inspect" the NSData returned by `gtm_dataByDeflatingData`. I know that the zip contains a folder and an html, but I don't know how to retrieve them.

Comment: I am not sure but I am now interested in finding out.

Comment: I suspect that I can't use it to unzip my NSData.